# Winter Bashing?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014

After looking through the different ways to get winter bash hats.. there seems to be a few specifically to do with negative actions but almost none that encourage positive community actions (i.e upvoting good questions)

- Imitation crab (Downvote 5)
- Red Shirt (Downvote 5 questions)
- Fear and Loathing (Delete own answer (I admit sketchy))

Shouldn't these hats encourage both actions?

Also, here in England, there isn't a 15th, 21st, or 31st month (Descriptions all use MM/DD)

Comment: Looks like a few people are earning these hats by using your question!

Comment: @Duncan: Unfortunately for them, Meta activity doesn't count..

Comment: @Martijn What? I want my money back!

Comment: `Also, here in England, there isn't a 15th, 21st, or 31st month (Descriptions all use MM/DD)` everywhere *except* America as a matter of fact.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

These hats *do* promote positive actions, they help keep the quality standard of Stack Overflow up by cleaning out posts that shouldn't be here in the first place:

- *Imitation crab* asks you to *keep the site clean* by downvote bad questions.
- *Red Shirt* is only awarded if the questions you downvoted were subsequently deleted or closed. So not only did you downvode bad questions, others *agreed* that the questions were bad.
- *Fear and Loathing* encourages you to self-delete a post, helping you to self-censor an answer that was perhaps just not good enough to keep.

There are, at the last count, at least 3 secret hats related to up-voting content, and one public hat that relates to using all your votes.

And Stack Overflow is an American site so they are free to use an American date format. You clearly understood that the date descriptions use the month first, so why do you ask?

Comment: I don't disagree that it helps with the sites cleanliness but I do think more could be done to encourage those that encourage people that produce good content.

Comment: @Sayse: there are several hats for those too. 3 of them just happen to be secret.

Comment: Thanks, its good to know they are there at least. As towards the date format, would it hurt much to use December 15 etc? (StackOverflow does state that it is an english website ;) )

Comment: @Sayse: the descriptions for the hats are super-concise. The date format fits with that brevity.

Comment: The american date format style is illogical http://odedran.files.wordpress.com/2012/06/go-america.jpg?w=240&h=235 Although it isn't really relevant to the rest of the question

Comment: @ypercube: it is not ambiguous. *12/3* would be ambiguous, *12/15* is not.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I would naturally read 12/15 as December 2015. Just because it's obvious to you, it's not obvious to everyone.

Comment: Unfortunately, like so many other things (imperial vs metric system), Americans are so certain that they are right and everyone else is wrong that no amount of logical arguing will change their minds.

Comment: @IanKemp: who said they are claiming being right?